# Git: how to find shortest path between commits

Tags: git, git-log, git-rev-list

Given a large git repository with hundreds of branches / thousands of commits, and an irregular branch merging strategy, how does one determine the shortest path between two commits?  In other words, What path of branches from earlier commit A to later commit B crosses the least number of commits?

(In my case I'm trying to trace the history of a 'develop' branch that had inadvertently been merged into feature branches via fast-forward.  A "shortest path" strategy seemed like a practical approach, but I've been looking through the help pages for git-log and git-rev-list [v1.8.3.1], but haven't found any option that seems to do this.  Am I missing something obvious?)

Comment: What do you mean by "shortest path"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but to find how A got to B you can use this:

```
git log commitA..commitB
```

You can use the `--graph` and `--simplify-merges` flags to make it more clear.

You can also prettify the log like so:

```
git log --simplify-merges --graph --pretty="tformat:%C(yellow)%h%Creset\\ %Cgreen(%ar)%Creset\\ %C(blue)<%an>%Creset\\ %C(red)%d%Creset\\ %s"
```

and get output like this:

[image]

Comment: But is this the "path of branches from earlier commit A to later commit B [which] crosses the `least number of commits`?" See [History simplification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Comment: Thanks for the picture!  Makes explaining this a lot easier.  Say I wanted the shortest path from 63556da to 0791d5c.  There are two paths, one with two commits and one with three.  I would want to see db7f4c8 and 1affc3f and exclude the rest.

Comment: @Lagrangian this is the shortest path to 0791d5c, you can't get there without the merged commits. Without the merged commits there is no 0791d5c. There is only db7f4c8.

Comment: You can use the `--no-merges` flag to not show mergers.

Comment: You probably want to add `--ancestry-path`, which discards commits that are not descendants of the lower-bound (`commitA`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not fully related, but this worked for me "to trace the history of a 'develop'" so that I got log with only commits on 'develop' (without commits on merged branches).

```
git log 25ab137285..2fbdf0a100 --ancestry-path --first-parent --oneline
```

`25ab137285` and `2fbdf0a100` are commits on desired branch (e.g. `develop`)

[--first-parent](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---first-parent) - main part

[--ancestry-path](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ancestry-pathltcommitgt) - believe that it helps